# SQLite - Is it possible to increase database in chunks during wal mode?

Tags: database, sqlite, fragmentation, wal

I am recording data quite rapidly in a SQLite Database, which results in a lot of fragments on the disc (typically 2500 frags/file). When I later on try to search through this database it takes a long time, mostly due to the fact that I have a hard disk drive (i.e., not a ssd). My goal is to get the fragmentations down to a minimum since this will increase my search performance.

I have tried setting the chunk size to ~100Mb, but if I exceed this amount of data it will start adding small records again, which results in fragmentations. I would like to have a specific chunk size that the database would increase when it's exceeding the current size, e.g. 100Mb -> 200Mb -> 300Mb. I actually though chunk size did this automatically, but does seem like it.

Storage capacity is not an issue for me, I can withstand some overshoot on the database size (database being e.g. 1Gb, but data is only 700Mb).

Any suggestions are more than welcome :)

The code below shows how I set up the SQLite connection:

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();

connBuilder.DataSource = dbFilename;
connBuilder.DateTimeKind = DateTimeKind.Utc;
connBuilder.Version = 3;
connBuilder.PageSize = 65536;
connBuilder.JournalMode = SQLiteJournalModeEnum.Wal;
var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connBuilder.ToString());

...

using (connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    connection.SetChunkSize(10000000);
    ....
}
```

Comment: What is 'chunksize'? That's not sqlite terminology.

Comment: Hello,
As far as I know it's an SQLite IO function
https://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_fcntl_chunk_size.html#sqlitefcntlchunksize

Comment: Hmm. In the standard Unix vfs, looks like that's only used when truncating the file (after a vacuum?) to make the file size a multiple of that size.

Comment: Yes, I saw the same thing. I checked this article, where they state that increasing the chunk size will decrease the fragmentations, which it does. I was just hoping that this chunk size was repeated every time the database got full :)
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Performance/Avoid_SQLite_In_Your_Next_Firefox_Feature